# solidity smart contract

Tags: contract-development

Anyone could help me to resolve error on my code this attached file
thank youn
[image]

Comment: This looks like school work or job application exercise.

Comment: Hi IncRaja! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please include source code as text, that will make more easy to try it and answer the question.